# In Firebase Crashlytics, how can I search crash reports by User ID?

Tags: firebase, crashlytics

I'm now using firebase crashlytics (com.crashlytics.sdk.android:crashlytics:2.9.1) and it's setUserIdentifier functions in order to spesify the android devices.

`void Crashlytics.setUserIdentifier(String identifier);`

However, in the "Search by user ID" the crash reports cannot be searched by the user id.
Is there any searching techniques for user ids?

[Custom Crash Report](https://i.stack.imgur.com/q83Xe.png)
[Search User ID console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cGEdK.png)

Comment: Mike from Firebase here. That sounds like a bug, can you raise a report via https://firebase.google.com/support/ so we can look into it more?

Comment: Thanks for comment, Mike. I'll make report.

Comment: hey mike, i want to get all user ids. is there a way to achieve it?

Comment: I am also facing same issue, @Mat did you get this now ?